# Couldn't install on USB storage or SD card - I don't even have external card?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean, internal-storage

I was just playing around on google play, but some apps cant install. I get the following error:

*Couldn't install on USB storage or SD card*

I have tried:

- Finding a certain file smdl2tmp1.asec, which was nowhere to be found
- Inserting an SD-card and then trying
- Dismounting that SD-card but still inside the tablet

So far, i haven't found an solution. Can you help me out?

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you can tell us what device you have, and if the device is rooted, has custom ROM, etc.

Comment: The device is a Sunnycube v7, and it is rooted. No custom rom, just android.